# Highcharts bar chart fixed grid dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, grid

I'm trying to make 3 separate bar charts have the same distance between ticklines/gridlines (not sure which I should be working with)

For my chart I want to calculate the height of the chart area from the number of data points within the data array. The length number should be multiplied with the amount of pixels the chart should be to create an responsive chart that has the same distance between the grid lines.

situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1TgJ.jpg

```js
$(function() {

      $(document).ready(function() {

            var dateArray = ['01-01-2014', '02-01-2014', '03-01-2014', '04-01-2014', '05-01-2014'];
            var typeArray = [107, 31, 63, 90, 30];
            var channelArray = [60, 31, 89, 10, 50, 30, 60, 31, 89, 10, 50, 30, 60, 31, 89, 10, 50, 30];
            var perDateArray = [100, 10, 90, 10, 90];
            var breakNumberOfCharacters = 10;
            var dataArrays = [{
              color: '#3366CC',
              name: 'Ticket Amount',
              data: perDateArray
            }];

            var channelArrays = [{
              color: '#3366CC',
              data: channelArray
            }];

            var typeArrays = [{
              color: '#3366CC',
              name: 'Year 1800',
              data: typeArray
            }];

            var groupPaddingValue = '.35';
            var barWidth = 10;


            var graphTicketsPerDateHeight = (30 * perDateArray.length) + 60;
            var graphVerkoopKanaalHeight = (30 * channelArray.length) + 60;
            var graphTickTypesHeight = (30 * typeArray.length) + 60;
            var marginVar = [48, 10, 20, 75];

            console.log(graphTickTypesHeight + ' - ' + graphVerkoopKanaalHeight + ' - ' + graphTicketsPerDateHeight);

            $('#graphsTickTypes').highcharts({
              chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: graphTickTypesHeight,
                margin: marginVar,
                spacing: [25, 0, 0, 75],
              },


              title: {
                text: ''
              },
              subtitle: {
                text: ''
              },


              xAxis: {
                categories: ['Adults', 'Youth', 'Children', 'Senior', 'Student', 'Membership'],
                title: {
                  text: null
                },
                labels: {
                  align: 'left',
                  x: -75,
                  width: 70
                },
                lineColor: '#C0C0C0',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                gridLineColor: '#C0C0C0',
                tickColor: '#FFFFFF',
                gridZIndex: 1,
                endOnTick: true
              },


              yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                maxPadding: 0,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: true,
                lineColor: '#C0C0C0',
                lineWidth: 1,
                tickColor: '#FFFFFF',
                title: {
                  text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                  overflow: 'justify'
                }
              },


              tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                  return '<span style=" margin-right: 10px; font-weight: bold; color:' + this.series.color + ';">' + this.y + '     </span>' + '<span style=" font-weight: bold; color: #000000; margin: 0 20px">' + this.x + '</span>';
                },
                hideDelay: 100,
                borderColor: '#000000',
                positioner: function(boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
                  return {
                    x: point.plotX / 2 + 20,
                    y: point.plotY - 10
                  };
                }
              },


              plotOptions: {
                series: {
                  pointWidth: barWidth,
                  //pointPadding: 0,
                  groupPadding: groupPaddingValue,
                  borderWidth: 0,
                  events: {
                    legendItemClick: function() {
                      return false;
                    }
                  }
                },
                bar: {
                  grouping: true,
                  dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                  }
                }
              },


              legend: {
                align: 'top',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                width: 400,
                layout: 'horizontal',
                symbolHeight: 10,
                symbolWidth: 10,
                y: -30,
                x: -83,
                margin: 30,
                labelFormat: 'Ticket Amount',
                itemStyle: {
                  "cursor": "default",
                  "fontWeight": "normal"
                }
              },


              credits: {
                enabled: false
              },


              series: typeArrays
            });
```

Here: var graphTickTypesHeight = (30 * typeArray.length) + 60; I try to make every gridspacing 30 times the number of elements + 60 for the labels and legend.

It would be great if I was able to just edit the height of the area that contains the bars but I can't seem to isolate that area and I have to change the overall hieght.

Hopefully one of you has a solution to this problem.

Many thanks,

Bas

Comment: can you clarify what exactly the question/problem is? I use the same method, getting a count of the nodes to plot, multiplying by a 'height per node' property, and adding a base height for the top and bottom margin. Has always worked fine for me, though I haven't been trying for absolute pixel precision.

Comment: Hi, As shown in the image, the vertical size of the x axis varies quite a lot. I would like to make these a fixed width, say 30 px, so that all of the graphs will be the same size and I can place other information along side of it on the correct hight.

Comment: I would also try to set `xAxis.height` to be 20*number_of_categories. That should make xAxis easy to separate space into categories with exactly the same width.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. it seems to work if I define both the height of the chart and the xaxis. I did have to add the other spacings and such to the overall height.